# Stretching iframes to fit a width while maintaining height-width aspect ratio (tumblr theme)

Tags: css, iframe, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm running into a problem with tumblr cutom theme creator. When adding, for example, a video post, they put it into an iframe with a set width and height. I can reset with width of the iframe and the video will stretch accordingly, but the height stay the same (as expected).

But when I set the height to auto, it squishes into a small rectangle, instead of assuming its normal width-height ratio (as I thought it would). Is there a way to make the iframe keep the ratio set for it in the iframe, but scale it up/down with CSS? JQuery is okay too, but CSS is preferred.

**HTML**

```
<div class="video">
    {VideoEmbed} // tumblr replaces this with an iframe containing the video
</div>
```

**CSS (not working)**

```
.video iframe {
    height: auto // not working (as in, not producing desired effect)
    width: 700px // working
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the ratio by using a simple CSS padding trick. You'll need to wrap the iframe in a container element, and set styles like this:

```css
/*span*/.iframe-wrapper {
 width: 50%;
 height: 0;
 padding: 40% 0 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 border: 5px solid blue;
}

 
/*span*/.iframe-wrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class='iframe-wrapper'>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XdlmoLAbbiQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</span>
```

Basically, you set the width you want the `<iframe>` to be, then add padding to the container to maintain the aspect ratio.

Comment: It's the right ratio now, but it's not the full length of the post; it's half, I think (taking from the "width: 50%"). How do I now stretch it to 100%, still maintaining the ratio?

Comment: Also, this didn't seem to work. The initial height and width were both 500px, so the ratio was 1:1, but the new iframe is not scaled on a 1:1 ratio; the width and height are different.

Comment: I think I found an answer based on your suggestion. I still have yet to test it with some non-square blocks, but I changed both the "min-width" and "min-height" to "width" and "height", and the iframe-wrapper to "width: 100%" and "padding: 100% 0 0" //EDIT: Nope, this always results in square iframes, my bad.

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to tweak the width/padding amounts to match the aspect ratio you want. If you want 1:1 you could do `width: 100%; padding: 100% 0 0`

Comment: Well, the problem is, I don't know the ratio of the iframe; every iframe is different. I was hoping for a way to maintain the ratio when scaling up without knowing that ratio.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I think you'll need some javascript to figure that out.

Comment: So it may seem :( I did end up finding a way to do it with jQuery, but thanks for attempting to find a CSS way with me :D